libxml2: how to use DTD validation with xmlReader interface when DTD definition is in a memory buffer?
I'm using libxml2's xmlReader interface to process very large XML documents.
All XML documents must correspond to a given syntax, which is currently contained in a DTD file, eg:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE myDoc SYSTEM "my.dtd">
...

The xmlReader code is like:
xmlTextReaderPtr reader = xmlReaderForFile(xmlFile, encoding, XML_PARSE_DTDATTR | XML_PARSE_DTDVALID);
while (xmlTextReaderRead(reader)) == 1)
  processNode(reader);

Things are working perfect, the XML document is streamed without significant memory consumption and DTD verification happens on the fly. Great!
My problem now:
The requirement for my application changed from using the DTD definition in an external file to using a hard coded DTD definition in memory (which cannot be changed by a malicious application user).
How can I get the xmlReader interface to use a DTD definition from memory?
Using a DTD definition from memory is decribed here:
Read in DTD from memory using libxml2
but the solution is not suitable for me since

it seems to read the whole document into memory
it does not apply for the xmlReader interface

I'm wondering if there is a way to let xmlReader use a DTD definition from memory, maybe somehow like:
static const char myDTD[] = "<DTD definition here>";

xmlTextReaderPtr reader = xmlReaderForFile(xmlFile, encoding, <whatever flags are required>);
        
xmlParserInputBufferPtr buf = xmlParserInputBufferCreateMem(myDTD, sizeof(myDTD), XML_CHAR_ENCODING_NONE);
xmlDtdPtr dtd = xmlIOParseDTD(NULL, buf, XML_CHAR_ENCODING_NONE);
        
< how to teach reader to use dtd ????? >
        
while (xmlTextReaderRead(reader)) == 1)
  processNode(reader);

